# AS3 #1008 Error, Level Change

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I know Im probably missing something stupidly easy, but Im trying to set up a level change in my game. Once the score variable hits 100 I want some dynamic text to change to Level 2, instead it gives me a null error specifically
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Cat_fla::MainTimeline/NextLevel()"

Here is the code:

```
var level:Number = 1;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,NextLevel);

function NextLevel(event:Event):void{ //Checks if player is at next level pionts.     Changes Level count.
if (score==100) {
    level += 1; 
}
levelCount.text = "Level: " +String(level);
}
```

It specifically pulls up " levelCount.text = "Level: " +String(level); " . So I imagine its to do with the String being there depite being declared as a Number, but I used a similar system to keep score and that worked fine.

Comment: It seems levelCount is set to null.

Comment: I don't understand how levelCount can be set to null, Its just a instance of a text box on screen with "Level: " in it.

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky is right. The only possibility is that `levelCount` is null. Add `trace(levelCount)` prior to setting the text property. If it traces out `null`, that's your problem. If it traces out `[Object object]`, we're missing something here. Also, you don't need to use `String(level)`. Just `level` would work. When casting a number as a string, to, you should use `Number.toString()` instead (should be slightly faster, not that it really matters).

Comment: Thanks Josh, tracing the Levelcount shows [Object, TextField]. I changed String(level) to just "level" which for some made the program work. Now the level is counting up every second once score hits 100, but I will just set it to = 2. Thanks.

Comment: You want to set it to 2, okay use `level=2;` instead of incrementing. But plan ahead, what if you'd want your level to progress beyond 2, so how should you program your game to determine level from score?